# How do I build multiple "targets" or "flavors" of an app using Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, visual-studio-2019

I need to build three completely different flavors or targets for my C#/XAML UWP app. Each of them will get placed in the Windows Store using a different name and will have different branding on it. Essentially, I produce three apps that have very similar features but need to be three different apps for business reasons. There is almost zero difference in the source code for these variations.

In Visual Studio, I created three folders and each contains the icons, manifest, certificate files, etc., for the target apps. I use a pre-build event to detect the configuration that I selected for the build and copy the appropriate files to the root of the project. Note that instead of "release" and "debug" builds, I have "release1", "release2", etc. and my configuration folders use matching names.

This all worked great with Visual Studio pre-2019! When I first set things up this way, it worked and was the easiest way I could find.

Visual Studio 2019 validates the  element in the project file and my build process no longer works. If I make this empty, something during the build process sets it. I think it gets set when I create app packages for the store and is otherwise untouched.

What is the better way to build multiple targets or flavors of the app? Alternatively, how can I avoid this  problem (and it's a problem since that value doesn't actually help me anywhere!)

So far, I have the way I do it now and I've also considered creating separate projects for each flavor with each project using all of the code from a shared project. In fact, I have a shared project that contains code that was once shared with the Windows Phone app that was part of the same solution. I just don't know if that multiple-project solution will work or not and it's hard to justify to the boss the day or two it might take to change the project structure.

Comment: Will it be a problem if you separate the three applications and create a project for each application?

Comment: I can move all of the code except for the manifest file, icon files, store associations, and the security certificates, into a shared project so all apps in the solution can share the code. I would like to avoid that effort if that's not the right way to handle this issue but I'm starting to think that this is what I need to do.

Comment: If you move the code into a share project, can solve your issue?

Comment: I believe that a shared project for all code and data files (images, etc) will work. Is creating a separate project in the solution for each app variation the only way to handle those variations? I have used build variants for Android and Targets for iOS but Visual Studio only seems to have projects and shared projects to deal with this as far as I know. I only used the build configurations to create app variants because it was similar to Android. It's clearly not the way to go though.

Comment: Yes, you need to create a separate project in the solution for each app variation.